# Extracting emails from a gmail account with gmailr

Tags: r, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I recently learned how to send emails in R with gmailr.

```
gmailr::send_message(mime(from = "email1@gmail.com", 
            to = "email2@gmail.com",
            subject = "The Great Subject", 
            body = "Hello buddy. How are you?"))
```

Now, suppose I have the account email2@gmail.com and I would like to get the body of this message I received. How can I do that in R? Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: you can try `my_messages = messages("The Great Subject")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on chinsoon12's suggestion, I got the body of the email with

```
A <- messages("The Great Subject",
    include_spam_trash = FALSE)
message(id = A[[1]]$"messages"[[1]]$"id")$snippet
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: hi, this is a godsend thanks, been trying to extract the id for a couple of days with no success. (just change the $snippet to $id). thanks!

Comment: Hi @GuyManova. It is a pleasure to read that I helped someone. Regards.